# Disable vibration in Samsung?

Tags: samsung, notifications, 9.0-pie, vibration

(Attention: Samsung's 9.0-Pie / One UI is different from stock Android)

Is there any way to **completely** disable vibration in a Samsung phone running their flavor of Android Pie (9.0)?

I already have `Settings / Sound and vibration / Vibrate while ringing` tuned `OFF`, but the phone still vibrates for various notifications.

The problem is that vibration makes this phone slide off whatever hard surface it's on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Accessibility -> Vibration and switch it off[image]

Comment: I don't see "vibration" under "accessibility". Are you also using Android 9.0-Pie?

Comment: yes men. my phone is running pie

Comment: can you share screenshoot in accessibility menu?

Comment: It's a bit of a hassle, bc I'm not using SE on my phone.

Comment: All my options are different from yours. I have: Screen reader; Visibility enhancements; Hearing enhancements; Interaction and dexterity; Advanced settings; Installed services

Comment: vibrate is in the accessibility menu and all android pie has this default feature

Comment: what model are you using?