# How do I disable all vibrations on a Samsung A51 running One UI 2.1?

Tags: samsung, vibration, accessibility

I've got a Samsung A51 running Android 10 / One UI 2.1 and updated to latest available security patch (1st September 2020).

Other users report being able to globally turn [vibrations off](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218416/disable-vibration-in-samsung), and this appears to have been available in stock Android [since 2018](https://9to5google.com/2018/03/08/android-p-dp1-refined-vibration-control/) (although it was available on Windows Phones in 2016...). I don't have the same options in my Accessibility menu - have Samsung moved this, or have they disabled the functionality completely?