# Globally turn vibrations

Tags: samsung, vibration

This question comes up occasionally - but in the hope there is now a way to do it I'll ask again.

Is there a way to toggle vibrations (specifically on Samsung's UI 3.0)?

Example use-case: at work, with my phone on my desk, I'd rather have a quiet discreet sound notification than a vibration (which is more disturbing to my colleagues).

At the moment, I'd have to go through *every single app* and turn off vibration for all notifications to achieve this.

I struggle to believe that Google haven't introduced this in 2021!

Comment: A little less hassle. Turn vibration on or off on per app basis, not for every notification of every app individually: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215658/218526

Comment: I currently hesitate to close this question as a dupe of your previous question: [How do I disable all vibrations on a Samsung A51 running One UI 2.1?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230114/44325). Note that some features may be available on some devices but not on other devices, and Google doesn't fully control what Samsung (and other vendors) want to put on their devices.

Comment: @AndrewT. yeh, fair comment. The pedant in me did think that because it's new UI version it _could_ be a different question. (and I'm utterly frustrated than Android doesn't have this 6 years after the other 2 main mobile OSs did, one of which they've effectively forced out of the market)